Nested loops in R: How to append a dataframe column with outputs from an inner loop
I have a timeseries of hourly data spanning 10 years. I would like to calculate the integral (cumtrapz) of a function output that spans each water year (October 1st, year through September 30th, year + 1). The output of the function can be negative, but I've included an 'ifelse' to keep integral output greater than 0. The goal is to add a column ('output') to the original data frame with the integral results for each water year.
I've approached this with nested loops. The outer loop cycles through each water year ('this_year') and the inner loop calculates the function and the cumulative sum. The function produces the results I want in 'this_year$output', but I can't figure out how to append the original data frame (df$output) with the outputs of all 10 years.
The code I have tried this far is below. I've also tried to export a csv from the inner loop, but R crashes. I'm new to loops and would like to get this working via the nested loops. But, I'm also open to other approaches.
Thanks in advance for your help!
for (i in 1:length(years)) {
start.time = "00:15"
end.time = "23:45"
start_date <- as.POSIXct(paste0("10-01-", years[i-1],      start.time), format =  "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M", tz = 'UTC')
end_date <- as.POSIXct(paste0("09-30-", years[i], end.time),     format =  "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M", tz      = 'UTC')
this_year <- with(df, df[(df$Date >= start_date & df$Date <=     end_date), ])
print(years[i])

x <- this_year$x
output <- 0
y <- this_year$y
this_year$output <- 0
df$ouput <- 0
dt = as.numeric(this_year$Date - this_year$Date[1], units =     'hours')
for(j in 2: nrow(this_year)) {
funoutput <- y/(function(x))
this_year$output <- ifelse(cumtrapz(dt,funoutput) > 0,     cumtrapz(dt,funoutput), 0)
df$output <- this_year$output

}
}

